# How to make a new column based on nan conditional?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, where I was looking if cells of column player in df1 existed in column last_name of df2. I merged on column player and if it is present in df2 it prints the cell but if its not it prints nan(which is what I wanted). I next wanted to make a description column but only for the non nan values. How can I add description for all the values that aren't nan?

```
df3 = df.merge(df2, left_on = 'player', right_on = 'last_name', how = 'left')
```

df1

| player | team | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tatum | Celtics | SF |
| Brown | Celtics | SG |
| Smart | Celtics | PG |
| Horford | Celtics | C |
| Brogdon | Celtics | PG |
| Gallinari | Celtics | F |

df2

| last_name | team | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Durant | Nets | SF |
| James | Lakers | SF |
| Smart | Celtics | PG |
| Horford | Celtics | C |
| Davis | Lakers | C |
| Curry | Warriors | PG |

I changed the matched_player column name for readability with:

```
df3.rename(columns = {'last_name':'matched_player'}, inplace=True)
```

output(df3)

| player | team | position | matched_player |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tatum | Celtics | SF | nan |
| Brown | Celtics | SG | nan |
| Smart | Celtics | PG | Smart |
| Horford | Celtics | C | Horford |
| Brogdon | Celtics | PG | nan |
| Gallinari | Celtics | F | nan |

expected output

| player | team | position | matched_player | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tatum | Celtics | SF | nan |  |
| Brown | Celtics | SG | nan |  |
| Smart | Celtics | PG | Smart | a player from df1 |
| Horford | Celtics | C | Horford | a player from df1 |
| Brogdon | Celtics | PG | nan |  |
| Gallinari | Celtics | F | nan |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `np.where`

```py
df3['description'] = np.where(df3['matched_player'].notna(), 'a player from df1', '')
# or
df3['description'] = np.where(df3['matched_player'].isna(), '', 'a player from df1')
```